# How do I keep the newest data recorded always on the first row?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I have data recorded every one minute in a column. However, the data is recorded from top to bottom. This means the newest data will continuously be recorded downward and the oldest data always on top. Is there any way to keep the newest recorded data always goes on top, and the previous data is moving downward instead?

Here is my code (I have two cells to fix)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Me.Range("D" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Me.Range("B2").Value
    Me.Range("C" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Me.Range("B3").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I do appreciate your comment in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to add new cells at top.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Me
        .Range("C2:D2").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown   'add new cells at top, shift old cells down
        .Range("D2").Value = Me.Range("B2").Value
        .Range("C2").Value = Me.Range("B3").Value
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```